# Is it possible to do Solr faceting combining multiple fields, like distinct on multiple columns in RMDB?

Tags: solr, field, facet

Let's say I want to do faceting on the combination of two fields in my doc.

For example:

```
Field1  Field2
A        B
C        D
A        B
A        C
C        B
C        D
```

Will have the facet result like

```
AB [2]
CD [2]
AC [1]
CB [1]
```

Is this possible? I mean on the fly, which means the fields are picked randomly, and therefore cannot create a copyfield during index.

Answer (score 16):

You can group two fields using the [Pivot Facets](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HierarchicalFaceting#Pivot_Facets) which is available on the Solr 4.0.

You can run the following query on your index to get it.

```
http://localhost:8181/solr/collection1/select?q=*:*&facet=true&facet.pivot=field1,field2
```

Then, the result will be like :

```
<lst name="facet_pivot">
  <arr name="field1,field2">
    <lst>
      <str name="field">field1</str>
      <str name="value">A</str>
      <int name="count">3</int>
      <arr name="pivot">
        <lst>
          <str name="field">field2</str>
          <str name="value">B</str>
          <int name="count">2</int>
        </lst>
        <lst>
          <str name="field">field2</str>
          <str name="value">C</str>
          <int name="count">1</int>
        </lst>
      </arr>
    </lst>
    <lst>
      <str name="field">field1</str>
      <str name="value">C</str>
      <int name="count">3</int>
      <arr name="pivot">
        <lst>
          <str name="field">field2</str>
          <str name="value">D</str>
          <int name="count">2</int>
        </lst>
        <lst>
          <str name="field">field2</str>
          <str name="value">B</str>
          <int name="count">1</int>
        </lst>
      </arr>
    </lst>
  </arr>
</lst>
```

Comment: This is kind of what I'm looking for. I'm sure I can get my expected final form with this result. But the thing is that my current project still uses prior to Solr4(3.5) . Are there any approaches apply to 3.5?

Comment: There is another approach here but i don't know if it solve your problem. At least you can try it. http://loose-bits.com/2011/09/20/pivot-facets-solr.html