# Solr query to combine date range faceting and pivot faceting

Tags: solr, facet, date-range

This question is related to: [Solr - count documents in the range of two date fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47761539/1333610)

In my schema, I have a DateRangeField called `dateRange` like mentioned in the other question.

I can do range facet queries on this field using this:

```
/select
?wt=json
&q=*:*
&facet=true
&facet.range=dateRange
&facet.range.start=NOW/DAY-30DAYS
&facet.range.end=NOW/DAY%2B1DAYS
&facet.range.gap=%2B1DAY
&rows=0
```

Now I have another string multi-valued field called `interests` on which I want to further bucket the date facets. Here is an example document:

```
{
  "id": "3",
  "dateRange": "[2017-12-08T00:00:00Z TO 2017-12-10T03:45:55.567Z]",
  "interests": ["hockey", "soccer"]
}
```

So I want to combine [pivot faceting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13856457/1333610) with the range faceting query I am doing above. Is there a way to do this?

As an alternative, I looked at going the [JSON faceting](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/SOLR-to-pivot-on-date-range-query-td4223503.html) route. But I can't get even the date range query to work. Here is the query:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/gs2/query -d 'q=*:*&rows=0&
json.facet={ 
  dates_f : { 
    type : range, 
    field : dateRange, 
    start : "2017-12-01T00:00:00Z",
    end : "2017-12-14T00:00:00Z", 
    gap : "%2B1DAY"
  } 
} 
'
```

and this throws the following error:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":400,
    "QTime":55,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "json.facet":"{ \n  dates_f : { \n    type : range, \n    field : dateRange, \n    start : \"2017-12-01T00:00:00Z\",\n    end : \"2017-12-14T00:00:00Z\", \n    gap : \"+1DAY\"\n  } \n} \n",
      "rows":"0"}},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException"],
    "msg":"Error from server at http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:7574/solr/gs2_shard2_replica1: Unable to range facet on field:dateRange{type=date_range,properties=indexed,stored,omitTermFreqAndPositions,useDocValuesAsStored}",
    "code":400}}
```

Not sure why Solr cannot range facet on a DateRangeField.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't try JSON facet API for this use case, but you could pretty easy combine pivot faceting and range faceting, by adding 1 parameter:

```
facet.pivot={!range=r1}interests
```

and replacing `facet.range` parameter with this: `{!tag=r1}dateRange`

Pivot faceting supports combining with range facets, by using [local parameter reference](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-CombiningFacetQueriesAndFacetRangesWithPivotFacets).

You will get results like this:

```
cricket 2
dateRange
2017-12-01T00:00:00Z
0
2017-12-02T00:00:00Z
2
2017-12-03T00:00:00Z
2
2017-12-04T00:00:00Z
1
2017-12-05T00:00:00Z
1
hockey 2
dateRange
2017-12-01T00:00:00Z
1
2017-12-02T00:00:00Z
2
2017-12-03T00:00:00Z
2
2017-12-04T00:00:00Z
1
2017-12-05T00:00:00Z
1
```

As usual full example is located [there](https://github.com/MysterionRise/information-retrieval-adventure/blob/master/lucene7/src/main/scala/RangeDateFacets.scala)

Comment: Thx for answering this qn as well :-). I missed the portion of the doc you referred!